# Does anybody knows a good dataset for malware families?

Tags: malware

Does anybody knows a good dataset for malware families?
What i need is a dataset where malware are already classified in families.
And is not duplicate of "Where can I, as an individual, get malware samples to analyze?"
What i want is the malware samples plus their classification. This means n malware which are the same variant.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with reversing, ask somewhere else. Also, try VirusTotal samples

Comment: Please read the question. It is not a duplicate.